# T-SQL - Calculate Average for every 4 month sequentially

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Column1 Date         Data  Column2   Avg
Test1   01/01/2019     1     2
Test1   01/20/2019     2     3
Test1   01/23/2019     3     4
Test1   02/20/2019     4     3
Test1   03/20/2019     5     1
Test1   04/20/2019     6     2
Test1   05/20/2019     7     0
Test1   06/20/2019     8     1
Test1   07/20/2019     9     1
Test1   08/20/2019     10    2
Test1   09/20/2019     11    3
Test1   10/20/2019     12    4
Test1   01/01/2020     13    6
Test1   02/01/2020     14    8
Test1   03/01/2020     15    9
Test1   04/01/2020     16    1
```

I need a column in a select statement to Temp table that creates an additional column called Avg which would Take the values sequentially from Column2 and divide it by (Average of Data for every 4 month Divided by 30).
So, for example,

- the first Avg value would be 2 (from Column2)/ (Avg(1,2,3,4,5,6) (from
  Data column) /30)
- the second Avg value would be 3 / (Avg(4,5,6,7) /30)
- the Third Avg value would be 4 / (Avg(5,6,7,8) /30)

And so on.

Comment: Can you explain better how the numbers you average are chosen?

Comment: What you want the results to be would be useful too.

Comment: Why wouldn't the second one be 3 / avg(2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ?  Your logic isn't clear.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Its because Month of Jan ends at number 3. Therefore, it should start at number 4 instead of 2.

Comment: Hi Shawn, please have a look at the answer Esperento57 provided. It is getting very close to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51026/35):

```
select f1.*, 
case when f3.Average30=0 then null else f1.Column2 / f3.Average30 end as Avg
from mytable f1
outer apply
(
  select avg(cast(f2.Data as decimal))/30.0 as Average30
  from mytable f2
  where f2.MyDate between f1.Mydate and EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 3, f1.MyDate))

) f3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There is just a little bit of issue with this. The issue is if the Date is missing. The dates will definitely be in sequential order however there are times when some dates are missing. For example, instead of Jan, Feb, March, April it might be Jan,April, May, June. So it should average the values for the 4 sequential months for Jan, April, May and June. Thanks again for the help :)